# In kinetic js Rotating an image inside the canvas and scribbling on that image

Tags: javascript, image, html, kineticjs

Actually I am loading an image in the canvas and scribbling on it and then rotating. Its working fine. After rotating the image If I try to scribble or write anything the lines are printing as per previous co-ordinates (i.e, before rotating image).

Using this code I am rotating an image.

```
image.setRotationDeg(image.getRotationDeg()+90); (or)
image.setRotationDeg(90);
```

After rotating the image I am unable to get the mouse position (or mouse coordinates) correctly. After rotating the image i want to scribble on it normally.

Please help me out in this situation.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  rotate the rectangle and then draw on it?

Comment: yaa actually not rectangle I am trying to rotate an image and draw on it.

Comment: both the things rotating and then scribbling on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain about Kinetic.JS specifically (never having used it), but from a purely Canvas-oriented standpoint I would use context.save() and context.restore() methods.

Check the Kinetic.JS documentation to see if anything similar is available. Normally, when you rotate the canvas, you rotate everything, including coordinates. save() and restore() allow you to save the current canvas state (coordinate set and transformations), perform some actions, and then restore them afterward.

Relevant link: http://html5.litten.com/understanding-save-and-restore-for-the-canvas-context/

It's been a while since I worked with Canvas, so please pardon me if my explanation is less than clear. I do hope the link helps explain it better. Hopefully this helps put you on the right track for your own research, at least until somebody more-knowledgeable about Kinetic.JS weighs in.

Comment: I have tried with save() and restore() but has't restoring the context.

Comment: context.save();
context.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
context.restore();

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a nice tutorial which of rotating disc. This could help you.
http://www.techrecite.com/html5-canvas-disc-rotation-animation-using-kineticjs/